# InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-2.0

Im using ASP.net core 2 in an mvc web application. Im currently authorizing from an AD group on one Controller action, and it worked fine on the localhost so far. Now after publishing, instead of getting the log in window I get the following error:

InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

This is how I authorize the AD role.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Domain Users")]
```

Do i need to add something to the startup.cs or am I missing something else?

Comment: lacking time right now to do that. U know if there is an easy way to fix this though? @nyulan

Comment: show startup.cs

Comment: @nyulan: That doesn't work in ASP.NET Core. `AuthorizeAttribute` is merely a placeholder now. The actual work of auth happens via other facilities, i.e. there is no `AuthorizeCore` method to override.

Answer (score 6):

You need the following in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Comment: worked thanks. Any idea on a action that logs that authorized user out again?

Comment: Depends on your exact scenario. I don't think you *can* in a Windows Auth scenario. But, perhaps using ADFS as a provider.